# How do I make my discord bot delete my message and react to the message above?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'react') {
            message.delete({ timeout: 1 })
                .then(() => message.react(''))
                .then(() => message.react(''))
                .then(() => message.react(''));   
        }
});
```

This is the code I'm using to try and delete my message, then react to the message above mine. I've tried using `msg.channel.send('+:apple:')` but it just posts `+` instead of reacting with it to the message above. So I'm guessing the problem is `meesage.react` trying to react to my message but it getting deleted so it just doesnt do anything. Any other way to do this?

Comment: [MessageManager#fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that code means to react to the deleted message. It's impossible.

But there's a way to fetch the latest message.

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 1}).then(msg => {
//...
});
```

Then the `msg` is a collection of messages, so `msg.first()` is the latest message. So you can use `msg.first().react()`.
Full code:

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content === 'react') {
    message.delete({ timeout: 1 }).then(() => {
      message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(async (msg) => {
        await msg.first().react('');
        await msg.first().react('');
        await msg.first().react('');
      });
    });
  }
});
```